# How to find the matrix representation of a linear transformation and changing bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $\pmb{T} \in \mathscr{L}(\mathit{P}_3(\mathbb{C}))$ defined by $$T(p(x)) = p′′(x) + p(1)$$
Let  $\alpha = \lbrace{x+1, x^3, x^2+1, 1\rbrace}$ be an ordered basis and $\beta$ the standard ordered basis for $\mathit{P}_3(\mathbb{C})$. Determine the matrix representation $[T]_\alpha^\beta$.

What I have done is first to find $\pmb{T}$ with respect to $\alpha$, then change the basis into $\beta$.
This is what I have:

$$T = [T(\alpha_1), T(\alpha_2), T(\alpha_3), T(\alpha_4)]\\
= \left[ \begin{matrix}0 & 6 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & -5 & 3 & 1\end{matrix}\right] $$
since $T(x+1) = 2 = 2 \cdot 1 $, $T(x^3) = 6x + 1 = 6 \dot (x+1) - 5 \cdot 1$, $T(x^2 + 1)= 3 = 3 \cdot 1$ and $T(1) = 1 = 1 \cdot 1$.

Now to change the basis from $\alpha$ to $\beta$, apply the matrix that that changes coordinate vectors in   $\alpha$ to $\beta$. Since $$x+1 = 1\cdot x + 1 \cdot 1\\ x^3 = 1\cdot x^3\\x^2 + 1 = 1 \cdot x^2 + 1\cdot 1\\1 = 1\cdot 1 $$ the matrix that changes the basis will be $$ P = \left[ \begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right] $$
To find $[T]_\alpha^\beta$, apply $P$ to $T$,in which you get
$$\left[ \begin{matrix}2 & 1 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 6 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right] $$

Is what I have done correct or have I done steps incorrectly or just done the wrong method in general? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see you got the right result (except i think $T(x^2+1)=2+(1^2+1)=4$). There is a simpler way of finding it though (at least one with fewer steps).

$$_{\beta}[T]_{\alpha} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mid & \mid & \mid & \mid \\
[T(\alpha_1)]_{\beta}& [T(\alpha_2)]_{\beta}& [T(\alpha_3)]_{\beta} &[T(\alpha_4)]_{\beta}\\
\mid & \mid & \mid & \mid
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So you take the transformation $T$ on the basis elements from $\alpha$ and represent that in the $\beta$ basis.

So say $T(x+1)=2 = 2\cdot 1 + 0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3$, thus $[T(x+1)]_{\beta}= \begin{bmatrix} 2\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$.

$T(x^3)=6x+1 = 1\cdot 1 + 6\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3$, so $[T(x^3)]_{\beta}= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\6\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$T(x^2+1)=4 = 4\cdot 1 + 0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3$, so $[T(x^2+1)]_{\beta}= \begin{bmatrix} 4\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$T(1)=1 = 1\cdot 1 + 0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3$, so $[T(1)]_{\beta}= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

So in the end your matrix representation is
$$_{\beta}[T]_{\alpha} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 4 & 1 \\
0& 6& 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
like you found.

Answer (score 2):

Since:

- $T(x+1)=2$;
- $T(x^3)=1+6x$;
- $T(x^2+1)=3$;
- $T(1)=1$,

you have$$[T]_\alpha^\beta=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3&1\\0&6&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$There is no need to do a change of basis.